# How do I resolve these exceptions?

Tags: java, file, io, checked-exceptions

To be fair, I'm not getting these exceptions but merely trying to find a away to cover these exceptions. The exceptions are NosuchElementException and NumberFormatException.

Note: This programs works perfectly because the txt file is fine. However, introduce anything that is not a number and it will fail.

Here is the main class where the problem *could* occur:

**BankReader.java**

```
package bankreader;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BankReader
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        BankReader reader = new BankReader();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String fileName = "";
        boolean finished = false;

        while(!finished)
        {
            try
            {
                System.out.print("Enter the name of the file: ");
                fileName = scan.nextLine();
                scan = reader.checkFile(fileName, scan);
                reader.readFile(scan);
                finished = true;
            }
            catch(IOException ex)
            {
                System.out.print("\nThis file does not exist or had");
                System.out.println(" characters that were not numbers. Please enter a different file.\n");
            }
        }

        scan.close();
    }

    public Scanner checkFile(String fileName, Scanner scan) throws IOException
    {
        File file = new File(fileName);
        scan = new Scanner(file);          
        return scan;
    }

    public void readFile(Scanner scan)
    {
        String accountNumber = "";
        double accountBalance = -1;
        Bank bank = new Bank();

        while(scan.hasNext())
        {
            accountNumber = scan.next();
            accountBalance = Double.parseDouble(scan.next());

            BankAccount bankAccount = new BankAccount(accountNumber, accountBalance);
            bank.addAccount(bankAccount);
        }

        if (bank.numberOfAccounts() > 0)
        {
            BankAccount maxBalance = bank.getHighestBalance();
            System.out.println(maxBalance.getAccountNumber() + ": " + "$" + maxBalance.getBalance());
        }
        else
            System.out.println("\nThe file had no accounts to compare.");
    }
}
```

Here is the txt file I'm working with:

```
346583155444415 10000.50
379611594300656 5000.37
378237817391487 7500.15
378188243444731 2500.89
374722872163487 25000.10
374479622218034 15000.59
342947150643707 100000.77
```

So even though this is my own txt file, what if I was accessing a text file that a character that wasn't a number or had an account number but no balance and vice versa. I would like to know how I can deal with these exceptions.

**What I've tried:**

I've tried to do scan.nextLine() to move away from the exception but it just introduces another exception.

I've also tried to use a method that uses regex to check if the string is a number. The problem is I'm using a variable that is not a string and I would rather not create more checks.

It seems to me that no more what I do, I can't recover my scanner after an exception has occurred.

Comment: Just to start: You need to include the actual exception message: put `System.err.println(ex.getMessage())` inside your `catch` to see what's really happening. Also, you may want to print the stack trace of the exception, to see which line of your program is throwing it (put `ex.printStackTrace(System.err)` inside your `catch` to do that)

Comment: Its same as notAGenuineConcernException() or didNotReadAboutExceptionsExveption and it will start a rollerCoasterOfExceptions.

Comment: @Barranka Well like I said I'm not getting an exception but trying to find way to recover from these two exceptions because they are of the highest importance.

Answer (score 0):

before parsing you can test if it is a double with scan.hasNextDouble and parse or read the number only then else you set default value and move next by reading the incorrect value and dont do anything with it